# Subdivide into separate objects

Tags: export, subdivision-surface

I'm trying to subdivide a plane into separate sections. Meaning each new square becomes its own object. On top of this, I want to keep a consistent texture. For example, I apply a texture to the plane, and subdivide it into different parts, but the texture stays in the same position if that makes sense.

I though I figured it out, but when I export, it's still one object with one material, despite making 4 unique objects and materials.

Any tips if that makes sense?

[image]

Comment: How exactly did you go through separating it and what are you trying to export it as?

Comment: Applied subdivide, made edges sharp, applied edge split, then separated by loose parts. Then for the material, object-relation-unique data and materials. I want to export as .dae

Comment: can u pls show us your material nodes?